# Heroku "npm install jugglingdb mongoose" Already did

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying Heroku, but i have run into a problem.

I deployed the Node.js app, but it crashed, I then tested it localy and find out that it was because it did not have run the command "npm install jugglingdb mongoose".

I did that and then it worked locally, then i tried

```
     git add .
```

and

```
     git commit -m 'db'
```

but then I get the message:

*nothing to commit (working directory clean)*

Then I think, "Okay, then i try to commit that to heroku, now it works on my local computer"

```
     git push heroku master
```

But i just get

*Everything up-to-date*

Then i try restarting it and try my app again

```
  heroku restart
```

But the logs says again = npm install jugglingdb mongoose

What could be the problem? I have also tried *npm update* and it did not update anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your 'node_modules' directory isn't empty and your modules are installed inside your local project instead of the default NPM root:

```
npm update --binroot
```